# Impossible NullPointerException thrown

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception, null, synchronization

In a webserver project written some years ago, I occasionally get a very weird and - in my eyes - impossible `NullPointerException`.
It occurs in a utility method for logging output on the console.

This is the faulty excerpt of the method:

```
try {
    Encoder encoder = Base64.getEncoder();
    if(logWriter != null) {
        logWriter.write(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        logWriter.write(" ");
        logWriter.write(String.valueOf(level));
        logWriter.write(" ");
        logWriter.write(encoder.encodeToString(Thread.currentThread().getName().getBytes()).replaceAll("(?:\\r\\n|\\n\\r|\\n|\\r)", ""));
        logWriter.write(" ");
        logWriter.write(encoder.encodeToString(log.getBytes()).replaceAll("(?:\\r\\n|\\n\\r|\\n|\\r)", ""));
        logWriter.write("\r\n");
        logWriter.flush();
    }

    lastWriterActivity = System.currentTimeMillis();
} catch (IOException e) {
    println("Failed to write log to file: " + e, Color.RED);

    try {
        logWriter.close();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        println("### Possible resource leak; unable to close log writer", Color.RED);
    }

    logWriter = null;
}
```

where `logWriter` is a `BufferedWriter`. The NPE is thrown in the first `catch` block calling `logWriter.close()`.

But: How can an `IOException` be thrown in my `try` block, while my logWriter is `!= null` ? `Base64.getEncoder()` cannot throw an `IOException` and there is no other code to be executed.

This is my stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "connection_0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1@1544725509" java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.jpuzzle.main.Logger.write(Logger.java:347)
at org.jpuzzle.main.Logger.verbose(Logger.java:187)
at org.jpuzzle.protocol.http.HttpRequest.onRequest(HttpRequest.java:1090)
at org.jpuzzle.network.ConnectionListener$Connection.proceed(ConnectionListener.java:438)
at org.jpuzzle.network.ConnectionListener$Connection.run(ConnectionListener.java:408)
```

My method is `synchronized`, so mutual exclusion should make no difficulties and I am out of ideas why this could happen.

Comment: You are catching `IOException e1` not `NullPointerException` you could try to catch: `Exception` which will catch all exceptions. - Therefore the error will be thrown and won't get caught.

Comment: But this would not prevent the exception, it would only supress them on my output side. And as this event is very (!) rare, it doesn't disturb me in any way - now, I am just looking for the reason for it. I don't see any reason for an NPE to be thrown

Comment: By the way, catching NPEs is not a good practice because you can prevent them using != null checks, but this is exactly what I did.

Comment: Sound like a race condition - is logWriter be defined as a static variable that might be used by different threads?

Comment: Synchronizing an method does not necessarily prevent the method not to be called in parallel. It just prevent the method to be called in parallel on _the same object_. So if `logWriter` is `static` for example, it can be nulled by some other thread.

Comment: Yes, logWriter is static. Always thought that this keyword prevents race conditions in a static context,  could I use a `ReentrantLock` to do so?
@Würgspaß And what do you mean with "on the same object"? Doesn't `synchronized` prevent parralel method execution for a method? What is it's purpose in a static context then?

Comment: Your stack includes `verbose()`, but I don't see that call in your code. Also, the NPE is coming from inside a `write()` method, so it's not the `logWriter` field of the class shown here that's the problem.

Comment: @erickson No, the NPE is comming from the method I posted in my question which is  called `write`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:**

Rewrite your `catch` block in order to avoid a `NullPointerException`

```
try {
  if(logWriter != null) {
    logWriter.close();
  }
} catch (IOException e1) {
    println("### Possible resource leak; unable to close log writer", Color.RED);
}
```

**Long answer:**

> Yes, logWriter is static....
>   Doesn't synchronized prevent parralel method execution for a method?

No.

Need a proof?

Run this code:

```
public class NowImFeelingZombified {
  static Object logWriter = new Object();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final NowImFeelingZombified zombie1 = new NowImFeelingZombified();
    final NowImFeelingZombified zombie2 = new NowImFeelingZombified();

    Thread t1 = new Thread("zombie1 ") {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            zombie1.syncedMethod();
        }
    };
    Thread t2 = new Thread("zombie2 ") {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            zombie2.syncedMethod();
        }
    };
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
}

private synchronized void syncedMethod() {
    try {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + logWriter.toString());

        Thread.sleep(2000L);

        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + logWriter.toString());

        logWriter = null;
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
  }
}
```

The output is something like this:

```
zombie1 java.lang.Object@1c34796b
zombie2 java.lang.Object@1c34796b
zombie1 java.lang.Object@1c34796b
Exception in thread "zombie2 " java.lang.NullPointerException
    at NowImFeelingZombified.syncedMethod(NowImFeelingZombified.java:44)
```

Howsa?

Synchronizing a method acquires a lock on the method's caller. Meaning `t1` does not care about `t2` (and certainly not about `logWriter`).

That's it. Read here for the [full story](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.6).

Additionally, a long time ago I wrote a 5-liner like this for a Util class I keep using. It saves me from writing `catch` blocks for closing `Closeables`

```
public static void close(Closeable closeable) {
    if (closeable != null) {
        try {
            closeable.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            //logging
        }
    }
}
```

Anyway, Java 1.7 has introduced [`AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/awt/Image.html)(which is implemented by `BufferedWriter`) that you may want to explore.